# java bankaccount program issue with a method

Tags: java, class, methods, bank

So for a HW assignment I have created a BankAccount class and a Bank class. It is mostly complete except I am having issues with creating a method to add a monthly fee. I have searched around and while I have found a ton of similar examples but nothing that works with what I have.

Here is the BankAccount class:

```
    public class BankAccount {

    String owner;
    int accountNumber;
    double balance;

    public BankAccount (String name, int acct){
        owner = name;
        accountNumber = acct;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = owner + " owns the account " + accountNumber + " with the balance of " + String.format("$%,.2f", balance);
        return str;
    }

    public double adjust(double amt) {
        balance = balance + amt;
        return balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Here is the Bank.java class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bank {

    BankAccount[] bAcct;

    public Bank() {
        //Constructor - will create an array that can hold up to 10 BankAccount objects.
        bAcct = new BankAccount[10];
    }

    public void addAccount(BankAccount a) {
        //This method will take a BankAccount object as a param and place it in the next avail entry in array.
        for(int i = 0; i < bAcct.length; i++) {
            if (bAcct[i] == null){
                bAcct[i] = a;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public BankAccount getAccount(int index) {
        //will return a BankAccount object given an integer index value as a param
        return bAcct[index];
    }

    public void printAccounts() {
        //will display all of the BankAccount objects
        for (int i = 0; i < bAcct.length; i++) {
        if(bAcct[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(bAcct[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public double monthlyFee(double f) {
        //will take a double value as a param and apply that value to every BankAccount object
        for (int i = 0; i < bAcct.length; i++){
            if(bAcct[i] !=null) {


            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the test class:

```
public class BankTest
{ 
  /*
   * test - set up a bank and add accounts
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Code to test Bank and BankAccount classes
    int errors = 0;
    double fee = -2.95;

    System.out.println("\nCreate bank1");
    Bank bank1 = new Bank();
    System.out.println("\nOne account");
    BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount("Peter Chang", 3021);
    b1.adjust(1000.0);
    bank1.addAccount(b1);
    bank1.printAccounts();
    System.out.println("\nTwo accounts");
    BankAccount b2 = new BankAccount("Roddy Piper", 3049);
    b2.adjust(2000.0);
    bank1.addAccount(b2);
    bank1.printAccounts();
    System.out.println("\nThree accounts");
    BankAccount b3 = new BankAccount("Leeroy Jenkins", 4028);
    b3.adjust(3000.0);
    bank1.addAccount(b3);
    bank1.printAccounts();
    System.out.println("\nMonthly Fee");
    bank1.monthlyFee(fee);
    bank1.printAccounts();
    System.out.println("\nErrors:");

    if (bank1.getAccount(0).getBalance() != 997.05)
    {
      errors += 1;
      System.out.println("Balance for account at index 0 does not match $997.05");
    }
    if (bank1.getAccount(1).getBalance() != 1997.05)
    {
      errors += 1;
      System.out.println("Balance for account at index 1 does not match $1997.05");
    }
    if (bank1.getAccount(2).getBalance() != 2997.05)
    {
      errors += 1;
      System.out.println("Balance for account at index 2 does not match $2997.05");
    }
    if (errors == 0)
      System.out.println("No errors found!!!");
  }
}
```

I'm stuck on the monthlyFee method in the Bank.java class. Any help is appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact operation you want to apply as a monthly fee? Just a substraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that :

```
public void monthlyFee(double f) {
        //will take a double value as a param and apply that value to every BankAccount object
        for (int i = 0; i < bAcct.length; i++){
            if(bAcct[i] !=null) {
                bAcct[i].adjust(f);
            }
        }
    }
```

Removed the return from the monthlyFee method as you were not using it and it wasn't clear what you would expect it to return.

By the way if I were you, I'd use [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of Array, that would save your some unecessary hassle.

Comment: oh shoot, that was my issue, I was too focused on what was going on in the method I didn't think about that!  I didn't expect it to return anything, just a dumb oversight on my part.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use your `adjust` method on each of your accounts in the loop with the fee amount provided.